# Wordpress API settings not savnig

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a pretty simple settings page for my plugin. here is the code: http://pastebin.com/k5jeZ9aw

It has just one text field and shows fine. However it does not save. Actually, when it gets to method 'validate_setting' it gets a void parameter (I assume it should get the value of the field).

I don't get neither any js errors nor wordpress debug errors.

I don't know if the problem is due to the fact of being using a class, but it does not complain about not finding any function.

Please anybody could help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after the whole morning dealing with it, just 15 minutes after having posted my doubt, I found out the problem. The code seems to be fine but I had some place else some other settings with same registered settings name. When I changed the name it started saving data properly. It would be nice if it threw some warning when this occures (two plugins with same settings name) but it does not complain at all.

It is not a common error but I hope this helps somebody some day.

Thanks

PS: I don't know if I should tag this answer as closed (considering it is my own question), or how to close it.